# Type Error : not iterable Array Function (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

```
 let grades=[4,73,67,38,33]
 
 function gradingStudents(grades) {
  for (const i of grades) {
    if (i >= 38 && i % 5 == 3) {
      return i + 2;}
    else if (i >= 38 && i % 5 == 4) {
      return i + 1;}
    return i;
    
  }
}
console.log(gradingStudents())
```

I am trying to log the results but the function is not working I know I missed something, I am a beginner can you tell me what I am doing wrong.

I tried what could but I dont understand

Comment: You are returning in the first iteration

Comment: You do not pass anything into `gradingStudents()`. It expects an argument `gradingStudents(grades)` That `grades` is undefined and hence why you get an error. After that you have an issue with returns.

Comment: @epascarello can you help with the return issue

Comment: You return on the first iteration--we don't know what you're **trying** to do so we don't know how to help. Are you trying to `map` the grades into an adjusted array of grades, e.g., `grades.map(g => the same logic)`?

Comment: Since you haven't included what is the end result you wish to accomplish. I can only provide you with some advice. (1) Start with an empty array and see if you can get a result you want. (2) Next, start adding elements to the array, in this case, just start with one element, and do the code changes to make it work. (3) Keep doing the previous step as you add new elements. (4) Format your code to make it easier to read. (5) Use variable names that explain what they are holding. For example, instead of `i`, use `elem` as `element`, or if `i` means an index, use `index`.

Comment: (6) move the logic used in the if statement inside a function and give the function a name that can be understood `function isGradeGreaterThanMinimum(int grade){ ... }`. It will make your whole code easier to understand.

Comment: It is impossible to help since you did not say what you were trying to accomplish. But we solved your original issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

im a beginner to
i know this is not the best way to display the result of GrandingStudents Function but it works
i think this is not a good idea to make a return in a loop.
the loop will break at the first iteration

[My Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76ukL.png)

Comment: This answer doesn't really contain any information other than a link. That code should be in text, in the answer itself. If you want to *also* link offsite that's ok, but the answer should be self-contained.

Comment: @Sebastien Thank you for the help It worked but, you forgot the else at the end it caused it to repeat numbers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your functions expects an argument.

While calling function, you are not passing any argument.

Be sure to call your function with argument.
Such as,

```
console.log(gradingStudents(grades))
```